# React select default value on render doesn't change the selected input value + title on change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After a couple of trials i have managed to create a React select dropdown with dynamic data for each sector.

Now, i have a problem that i am not able to create a default value on render.

I get all the dynamic values, but i would like to have one default value for instance: **Select...** i have managed to add one static, but for some reason when i switch from Select Categories the title stays at: Select...

```
WerkgeverList = () => {
    const werkgeversArray = [];

    const AlleWerkgevers = [
        ...new Set(this.state.opleidingen.map(q => q.opleiding_werkgever)),
    ];

    AlleWerkgevers.map(werkgever => {
        return werkgeversArray.push({ title: werkgever, value: werkgever });
    });

    console.log(werkgeversArray);

    return werkgeversArray;
};
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: change `title` to `label` and see if that works for you

Comment: @Rikin can't because the title is the prop.

Comment: how are you rendering this list?

Comment: Could you add the full code for the class component that uses this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your default value in the state, then add an event listener to track the changes and update the state

```
<select value={current_value} onChange={() => onChangedValueHandler()} >
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot to change the state of the current e.target.value thanks!